# Помогите пожалуста понять в чём ошибка в этом коде

Tags: c++, массивы

программа "вытаскивает" номера из массива чар и ставит их в массив инт.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void cautareNumere(char str[])
{
    int numb[50], k = 0;
    numb[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            numb[k] = numb[k] * 10 + atoi(&str[i]);
        }
        if(isdigit(str[i]) && (!(isdigit(str[i + 1])))) k++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++) cout << numb[i] << endl;
}
int main()
{

    char NrAndChar[] = "affwsd577f. wwqgfv373sc. qwrfve8378";
    cautareNumere(NrAndChar);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?  Что Вы ожидаете от этого кода и что получаете?

Comment: я ожидаю получить
577
373
8378

Comment: но на выходе получается 58477 37233 8408588 -858993460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> я ожидаю получить 577 373 8378

Может, имелось в виду это?

```
for( i = 0; str[i]; i++ )
{
  if( isdigit(str[i]) )
  {
    numb[k] = atoi( str+i ); k++;
  }
  while( str[i] && isdigit(str[i]) ) i++;
  if( !str[i] ) break; // забыл в первом варианте
}
for( i = 0; i < k; i++ ) std::cout << numb[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: при компиляции получилось http://postimg.org/image/3q8kna8pd/

Comment: Ну так быстрей бы в отладчике посмотрели, чем меня заставлять винды под виртаулкой поднимать и там студию разыскивать :) Понятно, небольшой глючок в `while()` - индекс через конец строки проскакивает. Но смысл-то от этого не меняется.

Comment: P.S. А вообще, раз тег C++, то можно и регекспами числа выцеплять, хоть родными, хоть из boost.

Comment: @dunduk, при таком подходе к программированию (регэкспы в подобной ситуации)  Вы станете лучшим другом коммерсантов торгующих железом.

Comment: А мы не знаем на самом деле что за ситуация. Может и всю строку сканировать не надо вообще :) А может там ещё столько тяжестей будет наворочено сверху, что регекспы пёрышком покажутся.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вы имеете в виду следующее :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

size_t cautareNumere( const char s[], int *a, size_t n ) 
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && *s )
    {
        if ( std::isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) )
        {
            a[i++] = ( int )std::strtol( s, ( char ** )&s, 10 ); 
        }
        else
        {
            ++s;
        }
    }


    return i;
}


int main()
{
    const size_t N = 50;
    int numb[N];

    char NrAndChar[] = "affwsd577f. wwqgfv373sc. qwrfve8378";

    size_t n = cautareNumere( NrAndChar, numb, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << numb[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
577
373
8378
```

Что касается вашего кода, то тело цикла

```
    if(isdigit(str[i]))
    {
        numb[k] = numb[k] * 10 + atoi(&str[i]); 
    }
    if(isdigit(str[i]) && (!(isdigit(str[i + 1])))) k++;
```

не имеет смысла.

Во-первых, элементы массива `numb` за исключением первого не инициализированы, а потому выражение `numb[k] * 10` имеет случайное значение и более того в нем нет никакого смысла, так как вы стараетесь с помощью функции `atoi` извлечь все число. Вы последовательно извлекаете это число каждый раз со следующий цифры, пока не встретится нецифровой символ. Например, если в строке имеется число `12` и `numb[0]` равно 0, то вы сначала извлекаете это число при первой итерации. В результате `numb[0]` будет равно `12`. Затем при следующей итерации цикла вы извлекаете то же самое число, но начиная с его второй цифры. В результате вы получаете `12 * 10 + 2`, что равно `122`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто надо было вычислять очередное число во вложенном цикле. Например, вот так:

```
int
get_num (char *str, int num[])
{
  int c, k = 0;

  while (c = *str++) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
      int s = c - '0';
      while (isdigit(c = *str++))
        s = s * 10 + c - '0';
      num[k++] = s;
      if (!c)
        break;
    }
  }

  return k;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что очередная цифра для кода ASCII вычисляется просто как `c - '0'`, поскольку коды всех десятичных цифр идут подряд.

Вызываем и тестируем так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[1000];

  while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)) {
    int num[strlen(str) / 2 + 1],
      i, k = get_num(str, num);
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
      printf("%d ", num[i]);
    puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

А в main мы динамически формируем в стеке массив достаточного размера для результата (основываясь на наихудших предположениях).

--

Для C++ надо добавить

```
 #include <ctype.h>
```

А массивы переменной длины (по крайней мере в g++) в крестах все же есть. Вот вложенных функций нет (в gcc такое есть), жаль...

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ c.c
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
wy12 ejejej123dfjd 7755
12 123 7755 
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Comment: Вообще-то, это раздел C++.:) В C++ нет массивов переменной длины..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, в g++ есть. (добавил в ответ).

Comment: На gcc можно было бы ссылаться, если бы стояла метка вопроса с gcc, но в любом случае я не рекомендовал бы это делать.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ну, почему же. Пусть люди  знают, что существует в мире. Тем более продукты GNU весьма доступны и широко распространены. / А Вы любитель мелкософта?

Comment: Это использование расширений определённого компилятор. На мой взгляд такие ответы давать нельзя, до тех пор пока о них не просят. Тег C++ и отсутствие конкретных компиляторов говорит о том, что автору нужно решение на языке C++. А в языке C++ VLA отсутствуют. Равно как и в C их имплементация больше не является обязательной

Comment: @ixSci,  векторы нашего развития очевидно расходятся. IMHO в стратегически правильном направлении идет именно мой.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код выглядит как попытка использовать функцию `atoi` для перевода одного-единственного десятичного знака из символьного в целое представление. Функция `atoi` не умеет такого делать. Функция `atoi` переводит *число*, представленное строкой, в целое представление. Число переводится с указанной вам стартовой позиции и вперед до тех пор, пока не будет встречен нечисловой символ. Это вам совершенно не подходит и в том числе именно из-за этого получается белиберда. (Хотя и других ошибок в коде тоже хватает.)

Для перевода одного десятичного символа в целое представление не нужно никакое `atoi`. Достаточно просто вычесть из этого символа значение `'0'`.

Однако вашу задачу можно существенно более компактно решить через возможности `sscanf`

```
void cautareNumere(char str[]) 
{
  unsigned numb[50];
  unsigned k = 0;

  int n;
  for (const char *p = str; 
       sscanf(p, "%*[^0123456789]%u%n", &numb[k], &n) == 1; 
       p += n, ++k);

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < k; i++) 
    printf("%u\n", numb[i]);
}
```